# Unexpected behaviors with Ember View helper with "a" tag

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

```
{{#view tagName="a" href="#"}}
  The Link
{{/view}}
```

**Expected HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="ember-view" id="emberXXX"> The Link </a>
```

**Reality**

```
<a class="ember-view" id="emberXXX"> The Link </a>
```

Can't see the `href` attribute

Also tried `hrefBinding="#", href=true`

On the similar lines, I wanted to associate an action to it, so tried the following failure attempts

```
{{#view tagName="a" href="#" snippet}}
  The Link
{{/view}}
```

where snippets are `action="showHome", click="showHome", actionBinding="showHome", clickBinding="showHome"` (Actions here are for route transitions)

None of them worked, I know I can simply do

```
<a href="#" {{action showHome}}>The Link</a>
```

**OR** defining a view

```
aView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'a',
  click: function(){
    this.get('controller').controllers.send('showHome');
  }
})
```

to get things working but I was curious on how to implement it the **Template** way

Comment: what version of ember.js are you using currently? what version of handlebars are you using with this version of ember? Just curious because a simple <a {{action foo context href=true}}>Click</a> seems to work (giving a valid href=#) in the ember 1.0 pre 2 release I'm using

Comment: Using ember-1.0-pre, I think what you suggest might work, but I was trying to achieve it using the {{view}} helper instead of HTML tags(out of my own curiosity!)

Comment: ah my bad (clearly I wasn't reading close enough / long enough)

Comment: @Unspecified, in the `{{view}}` helper, include `Ember.Button` which will allow you to use `target` property that can be set to a `#`. It will resolve in a link with `href="#"`. In my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer in short (and a workaround)

```
{{#view Ember.Button tagName="a" target="#" action="someAction"}}Link Name{{/view}}
```

Answer in Long:

When you said you can simply do

```
<a href="#" {{action showHome}}>The Link</a>
```

Thats the only way you get an `href="#"` with some predefined routing action. But from a JavaScript application perspective, creating / extending a view is more meaningful.

When you said you also tried `hrefBinding="#"`, it means you understand that bindings are for **that** view. Therefore only (I think) having a dummy link in an `html` tag should not be supported from **templating** point of view. The proper way should be extending the view:

```
AnchorView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'a',
  attributeBindings: ['href'],
  href: '#' //
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I never used a Ember.Button before I think its time now :)